# save previous value from posted select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am having problem passing two select to $_POST

i have two select and when i post from the first the value is not been saved ,so when i post from the second select doesn't remember the first select value ,I want to pass the first select and save the value to select.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<select id="city" name="city" class="styled-select">
<option value="all" selected="selected">all</option>
<option value="Van">Vancouver</option>
<option value="vic">Victoria</option>
</form>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
<select id="dept" name="dept" class="styled-select">
<option value="all" selected="selected">all</option>
<option value="1">First</option>
<option value="2">Second</option>
</form>
```

and i am using jquery to submit the form in change 
when first form submitted select does not save the value of the selected option

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#city').change(function() {

           $(this).find("option[selected='true']").removeAttr('selected');

           $(this).find('option:selected').attr('selected', 'true');

           this.form.submit();
});
$('#dept').change(function() {

           $(this).find("option[selected='true']").removeAttr('selected');

           $(this).find('option:selected').attr('selected', 'true');

           this.form.submit();
});


});
```

Comment: Why do you have them in separate forms? Put them in the same form and they'll both be submitted.

Comment: Barmar have a reason

Comment: I also don't understand what your jQuery code is doing. You don't need to change the `selected` attribute, submitting the form will send the value that the user selected.

Comment: because i want each select to be submitted on change, not all of them

Comment: yes i can just write, this.form.submit(), but my question when i submit the first select than the second the first select value does not been saved

Comment: Maybe you should be using AJAX instead of submitting the form? Submitting the form reloads the page, so you lose everything unless you save it in a cookie or storage.

Comment: Ajax might be better then. Because each submission will refresh the whole page. And unless you're getting the posts and putting them back into the HTML, it's going to just default

Comment: i have no experience using AJAX , but i have tried and that didn't work.

Comment: $("#city").change(function(){

     var selected = $("#city").find(':selected').val();

      $.ajax({
          url: index.php
          type: 'POST'
          success:function(data) {
             handleData(data);
          }
      });        
 });

Comment: i have tried this but does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you were missing some commas and that you didn't pass any data. Try this instead.

```
$("#city").change(function()
{ 
        var selected = $("#city").find(':selected').val(); 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "index.php", 
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                "city": selected
            },
            success: function(data) { 
                console.log("success");
            } 
        }); 
});
```

Also, you should be able to get the value of a select via `val()` e.g. `$("#city").val()`.

For normal submit:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<select id="city" name="city" class="styled-select">
<option value="all" <?php echo $_POST['city']==="all" ? "selected" : "" ?>>all</option>
<option value="Van" <?php echo $_POST['city']==="Van" ? "selected" : "" ?>>Vancouver</option>
<option value="vic" <?php echo $_POST['city']==="vic" ? "selected" : "" ?>>Victoria</option>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey i have tried but not working, is this src include right (<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">)

Comment: ah sorry, forgot about making hte url a string, try again

Comment: You should check your browser console to check for any errors. THat's the quickest way to see if your inclusions worked and any other problems code-wise.

Comment: it give error in (handleData(data);), i believe it is a function, or not): just found the code.

Comment: it does work when change the select, but not pass the variable.

Comment: yes handleData is a function, I don't know what you want to do with the data afterwards. And what do you mean by "not pass the variable"? As in the post doesn't receive anything?

Comment: for now just want to print to see if it work.yes i mean post does not receive anything.

Comment: What's in `index.php`? Does it echo anything? Could also just `console.log("success");` in the success part (see edit) to see if it worked.

Comment: success,  all of this is in index.php, and when variable been post all query that displaying data changed depend in that variable

Comment: should probably also post your `index.php` code as well. Is your form html in `index.php` as well?

Comment: for now -  f(isset($_POST['city'])){
   $c = $_POST['city'];
   
  } want to print the post value

Comment: if your form is inside index.php, then it's best to just submit it, otherwise Ajax will return all your html again. So either split the php file into a second one, which processes the POSTS, or keep it as a normal submit but add php to your html

Comment: i have separated them but not working :(, Thanks any way

Comment: even in normal submit value received from post, but not changed in select

Comment: If that is what your html looks like in index.php, then it will always be like that, unless you start adding php in between your html which chooses your selected. Put an example in the edit.

Comment: it worked like that , with this jQuery $('#dept').change(function() {
       
         this.form.submit();
 });   Thank you so much